# Prevent power adapters separated from the device it was purchased with

Tags: power

Why are there no standards for products sold with external power-supply specifying  proper labeling to match the device and its power-supply? A manufacturer of an external hard drive uses a generic power-supply with the power-supply's manufacturer only on its label. Some products do not even give an adequate power requirement on the device so the user can be certain he has the matching power for it. With the number of devices using external power growing, it requires the buyer to label his devices himself, or risk the set becoming separated at a later date.  Most users here can fairly easily match the power-supply to its appliance, but most consumers lack the skills and the equipment to identify the pair. It would be wonderful if manufacturers cared enough themselves to identify the parts of a set so if they became separated, they could be easily identified as parts of a set.  Maybe if consumers became concerned and started returning products that were not identified as a set, there would be less orphaned power-supplies or the device they were sold with.

Comment: This is really a bit of a rant. P-touch labelers work fine for this purpose. Adapters are only one of a slew of possible accessories (AV cables, plug adapters, antennas etc.) that could become separated. You can live a more ascetic life (perhaps limited to a small side table in a tatami room) or find a way to organize your stuff.

Comment: Mountain out of a molehill dude...

Comment: This is a rant, not a question.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is not so much a question as it is a rant, but I do see few things that could be mentioned.

First, there are in fact standardized ways of labeling a device. In fact, I don't remember the last time I've seen a device which doesn't have such a label.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_symbols)'s a picture of such a symbol:
[image: Polarity symbol from Wikipedia]

In addition to that, you also have the DC and AC symbols. AC is marked with a tilda like this: ~ and DC is a dashed line something like this: _ _ _. This sign will be right next or above the polarity symbol. In immediate vicinity you'll also see the voltage and maximum current as well.

If you know how to decode all those symbols, then you can use any power supply that matches the requirements and the plug and everything should be fine. if you don't then call your government and complain about education you've been given. In my country, in elementary school, we have a (compulsory) subject called general technical education where such things are taught

Now a tiny little bit about why you have external power bricks...

Well in the world, you have a tendency towards highly complicated regulations for equipment that's directly connected to AC mains. Quite often, countries and regions will require local certification. So if you have a product that needs to be exported, you need to pay for all of that if you have internal power. Not to mention that you also need to do the design yourself, which requires that you know exactly all those regulations and have a representative in each of those regions with some engineering knowledge. All of this will increase the price of your product and will force consumers to buy a cheaper device with external power supply. Why is external cheaper? Because you have a company that only does power supplies and takes care of all those regulatory issues. You just buy a complete product and integrate it into whatever you're selling.

I do agree that there are some devices which do not actually provide proper markings, but that's the side-effect of uneducated customers. As a company, you'll need to focus on what will give you more profit! If properly marking a power supply jack doesn't do that, then all money spent for it is wasted. Sure, in some cases it may not be much money, but in some it can. Also money is money, so why spend it needlessly?

Comment: I have had a quick look at an external USB hard disk that I have.  It tells me that it needs 12V DC, and the connector is tip positive.  But it doesn't tell me what current it draws.  Without that information, I have no way to tell if a given power supply will be adequate.

Comment: @Simon B  And that's directly related to the last part of my answer. In such case, user's only option is to try to guesstimate the maximum current HDD will use.